# How can I strip the unused functions from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a really minimalistic jQuery version for my project that includes only the used functions.

Comment: jQuery file is a text file! It's really light to load!

Comment: -1: I'm not sure what you want use to suggest other than downloading the lastest jQuery library and rifling through it. I doubt it's that easy to 'just' remove the bits you don't want and withouth a thorough understanding of the jQuery library would probably cause more problems than it would solve.

Comment: The README file explains how to include only specific modules: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/#modules

Comment: It has already been answered... maybe you guys were a little too pessimistic about the comprehension of knowledgeable people :) This is a very valid question, though

Comment: This is definitely a valid question, sad that 2 guys above admitted downvoting because they didn't understand that you can do a custom jquery build. Should have been closed as a duplicate if anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't build a version of jQuery with "just the used functions". However, you can customize the build and exclude modules you don't need.

Take a look at the Online [jQuery Builder](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/), it does this for you.

Comment: Thats actually a very good answer to a poor question. Well done.

Comment: @Jamiec That is not a so bad question IMO

Comment: @roasted - That's fine. You're as entitled to an opinion as me. But considering the FAQ, this question is not a good fit for SO. (again, IMO). Hence it is closed as off topic - 4 other users agreed with my close vote.

Comment: @Jamiec ya,true, doesn't really fit for SO